# Disable video autoplay/load on Chrome

Tags: gratis, video, chrome

My data is expensive, but I often read NYT/WaPo/BBC articles on Chrome, and these websites have a tendency to embed videos that load in the background (or even start playing) without my consent. Whenever I see one I rush to click the stop button, then add to Adblock the URL if I can figure it out, but sometimes the video has already eaten megabytes before I scroll far enough to see it.

Adding to the problem, I have to disable Adblock on some of these websites.

So, I am looking for a Chrome addon that would block all videos on these websites.

- Gratis
- Works on NYT/WaPo/BBC at least
- Maintained, so that website changes are usually reflected within a week or two.
- Bonus if the video can be played by clicking a button, but that is not a requirement. If I really want to see the video I will open the page in another browser.

Non-solutions:

- [Disable HTML5 Autoplay](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-html5-autoplay/efdhoaajjjgckpbkoglidkeendpkolai): Not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [HTML Content Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-content-blocker/nobnkgabkebhhlgfddbemmefjnjnahoe/related)? It gives you five content options to block: JavaScript, CSS, Image, Object, and Media. If you click 'Media', it should stop auto-loading and auto-playing of videos. The extension is

- gratis,
- seems to be working on the sites that you mentioned (for me),
- it was last updated on October 16, 2017, so it seems to be maintained,

BUT

- it wouldn't play your video by clicking the button: you would need to deactivate the blocking first.

Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Surely there is a Chrome Flag for this?